# Detecting a Redirect

Tags: r, redirect, httr

I have to check in a r-script whether a get request is redirected or not (and the page is reachable).
This is my approach so far:

- The URL of the response must be the same like the request URL (with attached "/")
- The status code must be 200

```
r <- httr::HEAD(url=url)
if(((r$url != url) & (paste0(r$url, "/") != url)) | r$status_code != "200") {
    warning(paste0(url, ": ", "Request failed."))
    return(FALSE)
}
```

It works pretty well most of the time but URLs like `https://www.google.ch/url?test=test` don't work as Google is responding with a redirecting note:

[image]

Is there a decent way to detect such "bad" URLs?